# Is it possible to "export" a worksheet with utf-8 encoding with Excel 2016 without using a stream?

Tags: json, excel, vba, utf-8, export

I am working on a macro that is importing a JSON file into a worksheet and replacing strings within the file. Therefor I have a worksheet with old/new columns.
After processing is done, the original file JSON is renamed, and the newly created worksheet get's Exported/SavedAs to an updated JSON file with the original name.

I've had many attempts (of different code)and searched on many forums, but there always seems to be a catch. Of course streams work, but since I do have a JSON file format it took me a while to find that out, because the context is often txt or csv.

Is it possible with Excel 2016 to do this with a correct UTF-8 encoding and without using an Objectstream?

Comment: Seems you are conflating "worksheet" and "workbook". A `Worksheet` isn't an Excel file, and a `Workbook` *contains* worksheets, and is a compressed XML format whose heading says `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` - so it appears Excel files are already UTF-8 encoded. If I understand correctly, you're trying to export the data into a text file, using VBA code, and you'd like that text file to be UTF-8 encoded? If so, your post is missing the code you're using to do that. If not, please clarify.

Comment: The Excel 2016 Information in the title was intentional, because I saw incomplete remarks where the 2016 Version changed.

Comment: What's wrong with using a stream?

Comment: I had plenty of tries, thats why I didn't post any code, because there are many examples of code that work. And I did mean worksheet.
There is nothing wrong with a stream, but it is not the intuitive way to go, that's why I asked for changes in Excel 2016 (originally).

Comment: I got that Idea from a different forum (Herbers), but can't use xlCSVUTF8. I did't offer a link, because I wasn't sure I am allowed to use links to external sites.

Comment: Well AFAIK JSON isn't a natively supported file format, so you'll have to write the export yourself. And since VBA doesn't natively output UTF-8, you'll need a way to specify an encoding for the file-writing - might not be intuitive, but a stream would do that. FWIW streams *are* a pretty standard way of writing to files.

Comment: Ok thank's I got that, just had hope that Microsoft changed the UTF-8 behaviour (xlCSVUTF8), but since that didn't work for me I'll go with the stream.

Comment: Why are Excel and VBA involved at all? Are you using Excel functions that don't have equivalents elsewhere? If not, consider PowerShell.

Comment: There is the translation table with old and new columns of the single entry's, that's already in a workbook. Another point, is, that I am not a programmer, and therefor VBA is less of an obstacle, since you can learn from record macro.